# What insect is featured in this picture?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

At the end of the summer, we've been finding these insects in our apartment complex in Baltimore, MD. What are they and do they bite? The length is about the size of a US nickel (We've had mysterious bites along our legs the last few days and haven't found any fleas or bedbugs after turning over the bedroom! [image]
[image]

Comment: Please update with approximate size, location, and species-identification tag. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is a [cockroach](https://extension.umn.edu/insects-infest-homes/cockroaches)

- Note the flattened body, long antennae, "hidden" short head, and spiny strong legs

Without more details, location or better photos, ID to species is not certain. The most likely species to be found as pests in buildings in the US include: [Oriental](https://entnemdept.ufl.edu/Creatures/urban/roaches/oriental_cockroach.htm), [German](https://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/roaches/german.htm), and [brown banded](https://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/URBAN/roaches/brown-banded_cockroach.htm) roaches. Common outdoor species that also often come into the home or invade commercial buildings include two larger species: the [American](https://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/roaches/american_cockroach.htm) and less commonly [smoky brown](http://entoweb.okstate.edu/ddd/insects/smokybrownroach.htm) cockroaches. Both of these species are found in the highest abundance in the Southeastern US.

Your image does not immediately convince me you have one of these species. Oriental roaches are black and smoky browns are also darkly colored -- unlike your brown specimen. German (vertical) and brown-banded (horizontal) have stripes on their [pronotum](https://www.amentsoc.org/insects/glossary/terms/pronotum), which your specimen also does not clearly have. American cockroaches are unmistakably large with brighter pronotums having darker spots -- again, unlike your specimen.

there is a chance that this is a female brown banded cockroach with its colors washed out from the poor quality photo.  (I kind of see some banding along its abdomen).

[image]

<sup>Female brown-banded roach. Credit: James L. Castner ; source [UFL](https://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/URBAN/roaches/brown-banded_cockroach.htm)</sup>

Cockroaches really never bite. You'd have to have a really bad infestation for this to happen. [Orkin](https://www.orkin.com/cockroaches/do-cockroaches-bite) supports this claim

Comment: Texas roaches are at least 3X larger as adults. Borax dust will control them if you can expose them to it . Borax is otherwise fairly innocuous. I blew borax into the cabinet containing the dishwasher and that has significantly reduced the number.

Comment: Borax can be dangerous for pets and kids. Use caution using this product. Follow safety guidelines recommended by product